# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS randomly freezes

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, freeze, git, debug

just freshly installed Ubuntu on my ASUS Aspire E15. It's alongside a Windows installation.

Roughly 10 minutes into my boot (maybe longer), everything will just freeze. I can move the mouse but no shortcuts work and no programs respond. I have to hold the power button to turn the computer off, then boot again. I think it may be related to a problem with git. I am trying to git pull in the background, often.

I cannot open a terminal or interact with my computer in any way with the keyboard.

I have disabled my AMD graphics card, reinstalled Ubuntu, installed Linux Mint, increased swap space and nothing has worked. I have been struggling with this issue for weeks. I am thinking there is some sort of catastrophic hardware problem, but Windows runs perfectly fine.

When my system is booting, some weird graphics distortion occurs partway through. It does this no matter what kind of Linux distro I am using.

How would I go about determining what is causing the freezes?

I am currently trying [this](http://andylinuxblog.blogspot.com/2016/05/asus-aspire-ubuntu-freezing-issue.html) solution and I will post an answer here if I don't crash for a signficiant amount of time. A solution that doesn't screw up my battery life would be better though.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with my Lenovo g505s backthen, and my problem is in the UEFI boot and the AMD graphic driver on Ubuntu. If you don't have problem problem with UEFI boot then I think the problem lies on the graphic driver. Try to search the right driver from [AMD Support](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download). Is that Aspire E15 the product of Acer?

Hope this can help you, atleast have a clue.

Comment: Yeah, it's an ACER laptop. I'll look around, thank you.